# $e^{-\beta \frac{1}{2}\hbar \omega} \frac{1}{1 - e^{\beta \hbar \omega}} = \frac{1}{2 \sinh \left( \frac{\beta \hbar \omega}{2}\right)}$

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

\begin{equation}
e^{-\beta \tfrac{1}{2}\hbar \omega} \dfrac{1}{1 - e^{\beta \hbar \omega}} = \dfrac{1}{2 \sinh \left( \frac{\beta \hbar \omega}{2}\right)}
\end{equation}
I need to know how this equality works?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Look up the definition of $\sinh$ and do a little bit of algebra. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function

Comment: Think of $1-\cos x$.

Comment: That's pretty much straight for the definition: $\sinh (x) = \dfrac{e^{x} - e^{-x}}{2}$.

Comment: I [edit]ed this question to [remove the display style in title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3135/290189).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $$z= e^{-\beta h\omega /2} \frac 1 {1-e^{-\beta h\omega }}.$$
You just need to do the multiplication. Then

$$z= e^{-\beta h\omega /2} \frac 1 {1-e^{-\beta h\omega }} = \frac 1{e^{\beta h\omega /2}} \frac 1 {1-e^{-\beta h\omega }} = \frac 1 {e^{\beta h\omega/2 }-e^{-\beta h\omega/2 }}= \frac 1 {2 \sinh(\beta \omega h/2)},$$
because by definition $\sinh(x)= \frac 1 2 (e^x-e^{-x})$.

Comment: This answers OP's question.  Why downvotes?

Comment: thanks, by looking at the number of downvotes I feel really stupid.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I believe we should let the OP to put some effort, before posting an answer to something this simple, that too after having some comments on his question.

Comment: Nash J, I completely agree, this is beyond preposterous.

Comment: @NashJ. Agreed.

Comment: @fayssalelansari I don't have any intentions of discouraging you. I just thought after getting the comments, you can solve on your own. Anyways, welcome to the MSE community!